# PDOException in Connector.php line 55: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, laravel

I don't know what's happening. I run migration successfully which means that the database info is correct. But when i submit the signup form i get this error. Following is my .env file code.

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:hRQre55GyKZGAx8u1GHZT/rg4m5O5Xln/+0BG8/qwdM=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mindspace
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Comment: Can you share your config\database.php?

Comment: looks like somehow it's not trying to connect with the information you have in your `.env` file. As the users suggests, it's trying to connect with the username `homestead`.

Comment: Have you check your  config\database.php ?